# Autofac resolve in deep layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, resolve

I'm having hard time integrating autofac in my applcation..

My application integrates with other applications, when a connection to another application is made its being maintained by a fitting "Protocol" object

```
// This class is inherited by a few other classes
public abstract class Protocol
```

I have a layer that is run by it's own thread and handles connection requests. For each kind of request a different kind of protocol is created (a different protocol object)

```
// For example lets say every protocol (Inhertiance of Protocol abstract object) 
// takes in ctor these 3 services + runtime configuration object:
public Protocol1(IFramingAgent, IFramingAlgorithm, IFramingParser, configObject configuration)
```

My protocol objects are keyed registered as Protocol. Also,
Each service is registered with key because each protocol uses a different kind that inherits from the same interface. Of course, all of these are registered as PerDependency (although I don't really understand the difference between this lifeCycle against PerScope, would really appreciate an explanation)

And here is my terrible class:

```
public class ProtocolsLayer : Layer
{
    private IFrameworkDependencyResolver _resolver;
    private IConfigurationService _configService;

    public ProtocolsLayer(IFrameworkDependencyResolver resolver, IConfigurationService configurationService)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;
        _configService = configurationService;
    }

    void HandleConnection1()
    {
        // What I have at the moment (terrible):

        // Resolve the fitting services (All keyed - key is received by the type, Resolve and ResolveWithParameters used here are my wrappers)
        var agent = _resolver.Resolve<IFramingAgent>(typeof(Protocol1FramingAgent));

        var algo = _resolver.Resolve<IFramingAlgorithm>(typeof(Protocol1FramingAlgorith));

        var parser = _resolver.Resolve<IFramingParser>(typeof(Protocol1FramingParser));

        // A parameter I get and pass to each protocol at runtime
        var protocolConfig = _configService.GetConfig<Protocol1Configuration>();

        // Finally resolve the protocol with it's parameters:

        protocol = _resolver.ResolveWithParameters<IProtocol>(typeof(Protocol1), new List<object>{
            agent, resolver, parser, protocolConfig 
        });

        //...

        // Theres gotta be a better way!! 
    }

    void HandleConntection2()
    {
        // Same as in protocol1
    }

    void HandleConnection3()
    {
        // Same as in protocol1
    }
}
```

Take in mind that I don't want references to autofac, meaning I can't use IIndex<> which I heard off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let the dependency injection framework manage instanciation.

You use a `ResolveWithParameter` method where these parameters has been resolved by the dependency injection framework. It is not required and you can let the framework find the dependency for you :

If `Protocol1` needs a named parameter you can specify it during registration process.

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IConfigurationService>()
                       .GetConfig<Protocol1Configuration>())
       .As<Protocol1Configuration>(); 

builder.RegisterType<Protocol1>()
       .Named<IProtocol1>(nameof(Protocol1))
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IFramingAgent), 
                      (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IFramingAgent>(nameof(Protocol1))
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IFramingAlgorithm), 
                      (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IFramingAlgorithm>(nameof(Protocol1));
builder.RegisterType<FramingAgentProtocol1>()
       .Named<IFramingAgent>(nameof(Protocol1));
builder.RegisterType<FramingAlgorithmProtocol1>()
       .Named<IFramingAlgorithm>(nameof(Protocol1));
```

Then `ProtocolsLayer` only need dependency on `IIndex<String, Func<IProtocol>>` (or `Func<Owned<Protocol1>>`)

```
public class ProtocolsLayer 
{
    public ProtocolsLayer(IIndex<String, Func<IProtocol>> index)
    {
        this._index = index; 
    }

    private readonly IIndex<String, Func<IProtocol>> _index;

    public void HandleConnection1()
    {
        IProtocol protocol = this._index[nameof(Protocol1)](); 
    }
}
```

If you don't want to introduce dependency on `IIndex<,>` for your whole application you can introduce a `IProtocolFactory` that will be defined in your runtime and create the implementation only for the registration project.

In your runtime project :

```
public interface IProtocolFactory
{
    IProtocol Create(String protocolName)
}
```

In your registration project :

```
public class ProtocolFactory : IProtocolFactory
{

    public ProtocolFactory(IIndex<String, IProtocol> index)
    {
        this._index = index; 
    }

    private readonly IIndex<String, IProtocol> _index; 

    public IProtocol Create(String protocolName)
    {
        return this._index[typeof(TProtocol).Name]; 
    }
}
```

Then you `ProtocolsLayer` class will look like this :

```
public class ProtocolsLayer 
{
    public ProtocolsLayer(IProtocolFactory protocolFactory)
    {
        this._protocolFactory = protocolFactory; 
    }

    private readonly IProtocolFactory _protocolFactory;

    public void HandleConnection1()
    {
        IProtocol protocol = this._protocolFactory.Create("Protocol1"); 
    }
}
```

You can also register a `Func<String, IProtocol>` which will named resolve `IProtocol`

`ProtocolsLayer` will look like this :

```
public class ProtocolsLayer 
{
    public ProtocolsLayer(Func<String, IProtocol> protocolFactory)
    {
        this._protocolFactory = protocolFactory; 
    }

    private readonly Func<String, IProtocol> _protocolFactory;

    public void HandleConnection1()
    {
        IProtocol protocol = this._protocolFactory("Protocol1"); 
    }
}
```

and the registration like this :

```
builder.Register(c => (String namedProtocol) => c.ResolveNamed<IProtocol>(namedProtocol)
       .As<Func<String, IProtocol>>();
```

But I won't recommend this solution because the intent of `Func<String, IProtocol> protocolFactory` dependency is not clear. Having a `IProtocolFactory` interface makes dependency goal easy to understand.

Comment: Cyril thanks! Can you please explain in more details how this IProtocolsFactory will look like? It sounds like the ideal solution for me

Comment: @S.Peter I edited my post to include a `IProtocolFactory` sample

Comment: How could I use it than without the exposing to IIndex<>

Comment: `IIndex<>` is not exposed, it is only kwnown by the project where Autofac is referenced

Comment: Oh I see, and another question is how can I do it without names? Because names could later on be changed.

Comment: You can use Keyed service. see [Named and Keyed Service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) for more information

Comment: Cyril thanks alot again..can the code for registering a protocol be reused somehow? It seems ugly to repeat this gigantic block of code for each protocol. And where do i create the IIndex<> before passing it to the factory??

Comment: @S.Peter You can create a method with generic parameter (ie : `this.RegisterProtocol<Protocol1, FramingAgentProtocol1, ... >()`)

Comment: @S.Peter you don't have to create `IIndex<>` *Autofac* will inject it for you. You just have to register it in *Autofac* (ie : `builder.RegisterType<ProtocolFactory>().As<IPrototocolFactory>()`)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just create a factory for each type of protocol?