# Autofac IoC factories abstraction

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

My application uses autofac IoC. It contains a layer that establishes connections to external applications (creating "Protocol" objects) - Therefore, I realized from my previous question that I should use autofac factory:

[Autofac resolve in deep layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908017/autofac-resolve-in-deep-layer)

I have a side project that includes all the autofac nugets and dlls. This one provides specific API which I use to register types in my application:

RegisterType
RegisterTypeAndAutowireProperties
RegisterConfigurationObject
RegisterInstance
BuildContainer
UpdateContainer

I believe this API is generic and fits for any application that will want to make use of IoC container.

My problem is with the factories. For example in my current application I need a factory for protocols (which are keyed and depend on many keyed services as well). Each protocol object is taking different kind and number of services and therefore I don't have a way other than making an explicit method for each protocol registration if I'm correct.

Now what happens in the next application that'll want to use this IoC API? It might not have the protocols this application contains, a case which will force me to update the IoC API for each application. Is there a way to keep my IoC wrapper generic - make it fit for any application no matter that types it contains? If you have any ideas in mind please share them with me!

Thank you

Edit:

I'll try to make it clearer, I use Autofac only. This "wrapper" is a project with the references to autofac that supplies basic API of IoC. For now I use this project only in application1.
But If tomorrow I start developing application2 I want to use this same wrapper. Therefore I can't have factories in my wrapper project that fit for a specific application. This is my issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "update the IoC API for each application"? Are you trying to create a wrapping API that can wrap any (or multiple) IOC containers (e.g. Unity, AutoFac, StructureMap)?

Comment: Edited, hope it's clearer now

Comment: Why don't you move the factories of each application to the application itself? Specifically, to the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of the application.

Comment: The whole point is that I try not to include autofac references in my application's projects

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't include AutoFac in your projects except for the composition root project. For that project, it is fine to reference the AutoFac library.

Comment: Still prefer to find a way without it